# TensorFlow Importing error ( Using Anaconda)

Tags: python-3.x, git, tensorflow, anaconda, amd-gpu

I have installed anaconda in my system, Python version is (3.7), I want to install TensorFlow as well. Since "python3.7"  needed in my system, I created a environment for TensorFlow (Using conda prompt) and installed "python 3.6". Installation and everything was fine, But now when i am importing TensorFlow, i am getting following error.

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
Failed to load the native Tensor-flow runtime.
```

System info():

1. i5 HP Inspiron, AMD graphics

tried downloading DLL files and pasting in system folder. but not helping.
Other solutions I found are through CUDA, which are only applicable if Nvidia graphics available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try out the following steps which worked fine for us.

**For Linux Machine:**

1)Create a virtual environment using the below command

```
conda create -n env_tensor -c intel python=3.6
```

2)Activate the environment

```
source activate env_tensor
```

3)Install tensorflow in the activated environment

```
pip install tensorflow
```

**For Windows Machine**

1)Create a virtual environment using the below command

```
conda create -n env_tensor python=3.6
```

2)Activate the environment

```
conda activate env_tensor
```

3)Install tensorflow in the activated environment

```
pip install tensorflow
```

(Here "env_tensor" is the environment name.You can use any name instead).

After executing the above steps please try to import tensorflow.

Comment: this worked, But When i try to install tensorflow-gpu along with tensorflow, Again DLL failure happens. However thanks for the help!.